# MLflow - Serving model by reference to model registry

Tags: mlflow

I'm having an issue to serve a model with reference to model registry. According to help, the path should look like this:

models:/model_name/stage

When I type in terminal: 
`mlflow models serve -m models:/ml_test_model1/Staging --no-conda -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5003`

I got the error: 
`mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Not a proper models:/ URI: models:/ml_test_model1/Staging/MLmodel. Models URIs must be of the form 'models:/<model_name>/<version or stage>'.`

Model is registered and visible in db and server. 
 
If I put absolute path, it works (experiment_id/run_id/artifacts/model_name).

mlflow version: 1.4 
Python version: 3.7.3

Is it matter of some environmental settings or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That style of referencing model artefacts is fixed from mlflow v1.5 ([Bug Fix](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/2067)).

You'll need to run `mlflow db upgrade <db uri>` to refresh your schemas before restarting your mlflow server.

You may find listing registered models helpful:

`<server>:<port>/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/registered-models/list`

Answer (score 1):

setting the env solved this for me:

```
export MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://localhost:5000 
mlflow models serve models:/my_clf_model/Staging -p 1234 -h 0.0.0.0 --no-conda
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.